# OpenSesame on Android to store RDF Triples

Tags: android, eclipse, rdf, sesame

I'm trying to use OpenSesame on android. Therefore i included the opensesame-onejar in my project.

When running the project, a exception is thrown: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry thrown in the info.aduna.lang.service.ServiceRegistry.(ServiceRegistry.java:37).

In my Code it appears, when I want to add a rdf-file: con.add(file, baseURI, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);

I'm creating my repository as follows: Repository myRepository = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore()); myRepository.initialize(); RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection();

Can you explain how I should rewrite the ServiceRegistry?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see answer for duplicate question at answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16540/opensesame-on-android-to-store-rdf-triples

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [Java Image I/O API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/index.html), which is used by Sesame and part of the Sun/Oracle Java JDK since 1.4, is not available on Android's JVM.

Not sure how to solve this. Perhaps not using the `onejar`, but just the individual jars that you actually need, might solve the problem.